# What plastic is this? (Raman scan)

Tags: spectroscopy

I can't recognize the Raman spectrum of this plastic.

[image]

[image]

It's not in the common plastics raman spectrum.

[image]

It is plastic adaptor for connecting sediment filters. Anyone got idea or recognize what kind of plastic is it made of? I'm studying the high temperature resistance of it. I bought a hot water sediment filter and using it as adaptor.

Comment: I did not see any fluorinated plastics in your reference spectra. PTFE comes to mind.

Comment: I can't formally be sure but that is likely Teflon as suggested above. Eventually PVC. I have noticed that you treat Raman spectra as the way to identify materials. While it is certainly true that most of them have their Raman spectrum, Raman spectroscopy is not the best suited for tabulated data and tables. You can use it as it if would be IR, but within a sample related and an equipment/setting related frameworks.

Comment: It does't match the raman spectra of fluorinated plastics, Teflon or PVC. What materials could be pipe adaptors be made of? Is there a plastic alloy? What you mean raman spectroscopy is not the best suited for tabulated data and tables?  And what you mean one can use it as if it would be IR? What are you talking about? It's a personal raman with 532nm wavelength laser.

Comment: The fact that is a personal Raman with excitation at 532 more or less resume my comment. I mean IR (on standard configuration and with textbook samples) does have fingerprints. Not so much Raman.

Comment: Did you mean raman with 785nm or IR spectroscopy?  Most plastics I have scanned have very clear raman spectrum (all the recycle codes from 1 to 7 I have seen have them). The unknown plastic above has very clear raman too. It's so difficult to do IR spectroscopy as sample preparation difficult. With my 532 nm raman. I can take it out to bars and easily scan the contents of closed containers, etc.

Comment: I mean that is difficult to compare Raman sp as it can be done with IR ones. You are right, can't be a fully substituted molecule as it seems you have both aliphatic and aromatic C-H str. Still for such a screw I would expect Teflon (now excluded), PVC, perhaps PS.

Comment: it doesn't match the exact spectrum of PS.. see https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/3127/SH9znP.jpg, nor PVC, see   https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/7128/IEUj01.png   what wavenumber is the alipatic or aromatic C-H str? What's C-H str?